# authorization library for asp mvc 4 like Ruby on rails cancan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am searching for authorization library for asp mvc 4 which works like cancan in ruby on rails (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Is there something like this?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership should do the trick. This will get you started:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

Comment: The default .NET authorization is role based and CanCan is activity based, they are different paradigms.